# how to solve render error undifined is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, foreach, react-hooks

Hi here my api return an array of four objects like this example :

res =[{ tutor 1},{tutor 2},{tutor 3},{ tutor 4}]

and I looped through them using the for each array method to return a view that contains the information of each tutor but something is wrong ,I get :

render error undifined is not a function (near'...responsee.foreach')

```
export default  function TutorsScreen ({ navigation }) {

    let [response ,setResponse] =useState({});

    useEffect(()  =>  
        fetch("https://elitestudents.link/wp-json/wp/v2/users?role=lp_teacher")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((jsoon)=>{
            setResponse(jsoon)
            console.log(jsoon)}
            ))
            

return(
    response.forEach(t => {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}> 
              tutors names : {t.name} </Text>
             </View>
        )}))}
```

Comment: You should use `map` instead of `forEach`.`map` will return a new array

Comment: Yes use map: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I tried map but I got the same error with map:render error undifined is not a function (near'...responsee.map')

Comment: Perhaps, there is no `navigate` in the `navigation` object?

Comment: no the problem is not with the navigation thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens only on the first render cycle. The function executed in your `useEffect` is async and will be executed on mount. However, the view will be rendered before the data has been fetched.

Thus, the `response` state is an initial empty object. The `map` function does not exist for an empty object.

I would use `undefined` for the initial state and return `null` until the data has been fetched.

```js
    const [response ,setResponse] =useState();

    useEffect(()  => {
      fetch("https://elitestudents.link/wp-json/wp/v2/users?role=lp_teacher")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((jsoon) => {
            setResponse(jsoon)
            console.log(jsoon)
        })
    }, [])

      if (!response) {
        return null
      }
  return (
    <View>
          {response.map(t => {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}> 
              tutors names : {t.name} </Text>
             </View>
        )})}
    </View>
  );
```

**Edit:** I might be considered more elegant to use an empty array instead (an empty array defines the map function). In this case we do not need the if statement.

```js
const [response ,setResponse] =useState([]);

    useEffect(()  => {
      fetch("https://elitestudents.link/wp-json/wp/v2/users?role=lp_teacher")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((jsoon) => {
            setResponse(jsoon)
            console.log(jsoon)
        })
    }, [])


  return (
    <View>
          {response.map(t => {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}> 
              tutors names : {t.name} </Text>
             </View>
        )})}
    </View>
  );
```

P.S.: In your question you are using `forEach`. This won't return the `Views`. As the comments already suggest, use the `map` function (although this is not the root of the problem).

Comment: oh thank for your clarifications I really didn't know that , now the error I mentioned is not showing any more ,but when I open the app it shows nothing no tutors name no just a white screen

Comment: You have not used the exact same code that I have provided. [Here is a snack showcasing your code](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/paranoid-donut).

Comment: thanks again for your reply , I have copied and pasted your code exactly as it is but still get the empty white screen , here is a warring that might help: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.%s, 

Check the render method of `App`., , 
View

Comment: Is the snack working? It is working on my device.

Comment: Yes the snack is works

Comment: Then your code is different then mine obviously. You could try providing a key prop for the outer view in the map function (`<View key={t.id} ...`) or show me your exact code so that I can take a look.

Comment: yes if you pleased you can look here I uploaded my entire project: https://snack.expo.dev/@ahmed-316/calm-chocolate         and when I try I it still show an empty screen

Comment: Try adding `flex: 1` to the parent view of TutorsScreen. [Here is an updated snack of your code](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/calm-chocolate).

Comment: yes thank u so much for help and sorry for my stupid mistake ,I don't know how I forgot the flex 1 thing , wish u a great day man

Answer (score -1):

just change the response you are setting in state

setResponse(jsoon) =>  setResponse(jsoon[0])

and try again with below code ->

const [response ,setResponse] =useState([]);

```
useEffect(()  => {
  fetch("https://elitestudents.link/wp-json/wp/v2/users?role=lp_teacher")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((jsoon) => {
        setResponse(jsoon[0])
        console.log(jsoon)
    })
}, [])




return (
    <View>
          {response.map(t => {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                style={{ fontSize: 26, fontWeight: 'bold' }}> 
              tutors names : {t.name} </Text>
             </View>
        )})}
    </View>
  );
```